# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result is null when using sweetalert for update confirmation

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, sweetalert2

I have a update link that I need to do confirmation before it's go to update data. I've built using sweetalert in codeigniter.

The flow I want is if the user click ok, it will go to controller for update data, and if the user click `cancel`, it's not going anywhere.

However the data is not updated after user click `Ok`. And when I do `console.log`, is shows error like `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result is null` after  I clicked `cancel` button.

Here's the html code

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

 <a title="Accept" href="<?= base_url(); ?>ControllerName/accept/<?= $j; ?>?id=<?= $id; ?>" onclick="confirmation(event)">
       <button class="btn btn-blue1"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></button>
  </a>
```

Here's the js code

```
 function confirmation(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var urlToRedirect = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href'); 
    console.log(urlToRedirect); // verify if this is the right URL
    swal({
      text: "Are you sure you want to updated data ? ",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        window.location.href=urlToRedirect;
      }
      else
      {
        Swal.fire(
            'Deleted!',
            'Your file has been deleted.',
            'success'
           )
      }
   });
}
```

Here's the controller code

```
$id = $this->input->get('id');
$data = array(
        'status'        => 'Accepted',
        'updated_by'    => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
    );

$result = $this->Model->accept($data, $id);
```

This is model code

```
function accept($data, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    if($this->db->update("schedule", $data)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Do you know how to run this correctly ?

Thank you

Comment: note: `function accept` returns `undefined` - but ... not sure why swal is returning a Promised `null` ... what should it return? and what is `swal` ... I know what `Swal` would be, but you've obviously created this `swal` yourself ...

Comment: Try `if (result && result.isConfirmed) {`. Sounds like cancel resolves the promise with `null` which has no properties and throws error

Comment: @charlietfl I have tried, but it not shows a dialog confirmation. It directly go to `window.location.href=urlToRedirect;`